# Function Works with Jquery 1.6.4 , doesn't work with Jquery 1.9.1

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm doing phonegap project with JQM framework.

On this project, i'm trying to do a navigation menu with swipe left (to open) and swipe right (to close).

The codes are working great on Jquery 1.6.4.

But when i import Jquery 1.9.1 to my project, it doesnt work. Button click works but swipe doesnt.

Dont tell me continue with 1.6.4 then please, i need help :)

Here is the function i have;

```
    $(function(){
    var menuStatus;

    $("a.showMenu").click(function(){
        if(menuStatus != true){             
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            marginLeft: "265px",
          }, 300, function(){menuStatus = true});
          return false;
          } else {
            $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            marginLeft: "0px",
          }, 300, function(){menuStatus = false});
            return false;
          }
    });

    $('.pages').live("swipeleft", function(){
        if (menuStatus){    
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            marginLeft: "0px",
          }, 300, function(){menuStatus = false});
          }
    });

    $('.pages').live("swiperight", function(){
        if (!menuStatus){   
        $(".ui-page-active").animate({
            marginLeft: "265px",
          }, 300, function(){menuStatus = true});
          }
    });

    $("#menu li a").click(function(){
        var p = $(this).parent();
        if($(p).hasClass('active')){
            $("#menu li").removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $("#menu li").removeClass('active');
            $(p).addClass('active');
        }
    });

});
```

Here is the body tag;

```
<body> 
        <div id="menu">
        <h3>Menu</h3>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d">
                <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close Menu</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" class="pages" id="home">
            <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#"class="showMenu" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false">Menu</a>
                <h1>Loreee</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <p><strong>Note: You can swipe right/left to show/close menu.</strong></p>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div><!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>footer</h1> 
            </div>  
        </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
```

Waiting your answers. Thanks.

Comment: `.live` is no longer used, it has been replaced with `.on`

Comment: .live was deprecated as of 1.7 and removed completely as of 1.9. `.on` is a way to go now.

Comment: i was googleing it, i knew that was something like that. thanks.

Comment: read http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

Comment: why did you gave -1 ? someone ? whats your reason ? i asked a easy but clear question, and i will never forget it, why -1 ????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `.live` with `.on` like so. Change

```
$('.pages').live("swipeleft", function(){
```

To

```
$(document).on("swipeleft", ".pages", function() {
    //code here
});
```

Comment: You can also use .bind() but .on() can also do event delegation, and is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

To find out incompatibility problems you may use jquery migrate tool:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```